# Can 'some' mean 'about, 'around'?

Tags: word-usage

In the examples below, can 'some' be replaced with 'about', 'around'? 
And also, are sentences below a correct usage of the word 'some'?

> 1) Some hundred people 
> 2) annual production of some 35 million units
>   
> 3) In 13 months, I flew to 14 countries and gave some hundred talks 
> 4)
>   he found his teen pal some 50 years later
> 5) annual production of some
>   35 million units

Comment: Yes, it can and yes, they are. It is also more formal that about or around. Especially in news writing about business/economics, for numbers. some is the same but shorter than approximately.

Comment: @Lambie could you add this as an answer?

Comment: And then there's "Some pig!", which has a different meaning entirely.

Comment: Then, there's what the lady of the night said to the computer...too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can and yes, they are. It is also more formal than about or around. Especially in news writing about business/economics, for numbers. /some/ is the same as approximately but a  shorter word.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all three can be used interchangeably.

**Some**: an unspecified number or amount of people or things. "here are some of our suggestions"

**Around**: (used with a number or quantity) approximately. "software costs would be around £1,500"

**About**: (used with a number or quantity) approximately. "reduced by about 5 per cent"